# Disable the text boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner to html. I have two text boxes say t1 and t2 If t1 is filled with some data then then other text box t2 should be disable. Please let me know hot to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this effect supposed to work when the user types in the boxes? If so, you need to specify that -- you'll be using Javascript to do it.

Comment: Do you want to have t1 disabled when some data is entered in t2 also??

Answer (score 2):

Based on your simple scenario description, here's an implementation that works cross-browser and without any third-party javascript library:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  t1.onchange = function(){
     t2.disabled = t1.value.length > 0;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
t1:<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" /><br/>
t2:<input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function verify(){
    var t1 = document.getElementById ('first');
    var t2 = document.getElementById ('second');
    if (t1.value != '') {
       t2.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
       return true; 
    } 
    if (t2.value != '') {
       t1.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
       return true;
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
<input type="text" id="first" onblur="verify()">
<input type="text" id="second" onblur="verify()">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score -5):

You can't achieve this with plain HTML.

Following the guidelines of [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/), you should first implement a server side check in whatever form handler you are using to process the submitted data.

Then you can consider adding JavaScript for a client side check. Something along the lines of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Disabling form controls</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="http://example.com/">
          <div>
            <input name="t1">
            <input name="t2">
          </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
          var t1 = document.forms.myForm.elements.t1;
          var t2 = document.forms.myForm.elements.t2;
          var handler = function handler() {
            t2.disabled = (t1.value !== "");
          };
          t1.onchange = handler;
        }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Although I would use a library such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to add event handlers in a fashion that is better protected from overwriting in a crossbrowser compatible way).

You might want some tutorials on [JavaScript](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/01/24/video-crockford-tjpl/) and [the DOM](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/10/20/video-crockford-domtheory/) so that this makes sense.

Comment: I tested this snippet by creating a form with the id="myForm" in FF3, Chrome and IE8 and it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated it with a complete HTML document since you don't seem to be able to comprehend how the script is supposed to work.

Comment: If "Changing the outer function block into José's design pops it to life", then that suggests that either (a) You are failing to put the code I wrote /after/ the form is constructed or (b) You are failing to include the () at the end of the anonymous function that is used to avoid adding variables to the global namespace.

Comment: Your code does not work if the script block appears before the form in the document. If you move it to the head for instance (where I tried it first), it stops working.

Comment: Yes, I did say "ensure that the script doesn't run before the form exists" in a previous comment. Normally I would use YUI's onAvailable feature, but this example was avoiding the use of libraries. Onload could be used instead, but then the script wouldn't have any effect until the entire page (including images) was loaded - users who were faster then their bandwidth would thus suffer from a form with the logic missing.

Comment: @David; I noticed your intruction in the comment when I had posted my last comment (gave an upvote after those updates; didn't think that the -1 score that your post had was deserved).